# How to use email instead of username for user authentication?

Tags: django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accepting email address as username in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778382/accepting-email-address-as-username-in-django)

The authentication model provided along with Django is based on
username.

What to do to change the authentication based on email instead of
username?

**To be more specific**:

With username authentication, to login user we do the following:

```
 user = authenticate(name,password)
 .......
 login(request,user)
```

What to write for the above statements if we are authenticating
using email?

**For form**:

I am planning to write my own form which shows the fields
email, password and the validation.
Is this the correct approach?

Comment: If you want people to log in using their email addresses and not their usernames, then create a custom authentication backend.

Answer (score 7):

I found [this snippet](http://www.davidcramer.net/code/224/logging-in-with-email-addresses-in-django.html) when reading a duplicate question to this one. Also check [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778382/accepting-email-address-as-username-in-django/778399#778399):

```
class UserForm( forms.ModelForm ):
    class Meta:
        model= User
        exclude= ('email',)
    username = forms.EmailField(max_length=64,
        help_text = "The person's email address.")
    def clean_email( self ):
        email= self.cleaned_data['username']
        return email

class UserAdmin( admin.ModelAdmin ):
    form= UserForm
    list_display = ( 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff' )
    list_filter = ( 'is_staff', )
    search_fields = ( 'email', )

admin.site.unregister( User )
admin.site.register( User, UserAdmin )
```

---

*Neither answer is originally mine. Up vote on the other thread to the owners for the karma boost. I just copied them here to make this thread as complete as possible.*

Answer (score 5):

Check out [this snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/74/), and read the comments for updates.

For the form, why not just inherit from (or directly use) the auth login form.  See django/contrib/auth/forms.py

Comment: Also see the django-emailauth project: http://github.com/redvasily/django-emailauth/tree/master/  which hopefully will someday support EAUT style login as well.

Answer (score 3):

Please see the below link which illustrates the way in which we should solve the problem.

http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/c943ede66e6807c

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you can just mask the username with the word "email" and all the usernames will just have the email show up instead.

Comment: I think we can't use username field for email as we could  not able to store @ symbol in the username.

Comment: Hmm....well, I don't know why not but if that's the case then my suggestion isn't very helpful.

Comment: In Django 1.2, you @ is allowed on usernames, so this solution could work (and its pretty simple).

Comment: It only allows e-mails with a maximum of 30 chars, though. Extend that by adding `from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

AuthenticationForm.base_fields['username'].max_length = 75` to models.py. Thanks sijojamesjohn.

Answer (score -1):

Unless I missed something, the solution should be really simple; just make a normal form with a text field and a password field.  When the HTTP request method is POST, try to fetch the user with the given e-mail address.  If such a user doesn't exist, you have an error.  If the user does exist, try to authenticate the user and log her in.

Comment: This is not using the Django ORM