# Accepting email address as username in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication

Is there a good way to do this in Django without rolling my own authentication system?  I want the username to be the user's email address instead of them creating a username.

Please advise

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704168/how-to-use-email-instead-of-username-for-user-authentication

Answer (score 35):

For anyone else wanting to do this, I'd recommend taking a look at [django-email-as-username](https://github.com/dabapps/django-email-as-username) which is a pretty comprehensive solution, that includes patching up the admin and the `createsuperuser` management commands, amongst other bits and pieces.

**Edit**: As of Django 1.5 onwards you should consider using a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user) instead of [django-email-as-username](https://github.com/dabapps/django-email-as-username).

Comment: If you decide that a custom user model is the best option, you might want to check [this tutorial](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2013/08/07/migrating-custom-user-model-django/) on the caktus group blog, it resembles [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) given in django docs but take cares of some details needed for a production environment (e.g. Permissions).

Comment: For Django 1.5 and above, the [django-custom-user](https://github.com/jcugat/django-custom-user) app contains a canned custom user model that implements this.

Answer (score 29):

Here's what we do. It isn't a "complete" solution, but it does much of what you're looking for.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ('email',)
    username = forms.EmailField(max_length=64,
                                help_text="The person's email address.")
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['username']
        return email

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = UserForm
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')
    list_filter = ('is_staff',)
    search_fields = ('email',)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: Works for me. Although I can see this being confusing for future maintainers.

Comment: that is probably the smartest answer I have ever seen in SO.

Comment: on admin Create User this: exclude = ('email',) throw me an error that key['email'] is missing from UserForm, that is obvious.

Answer (score 22):

Here is one way to do it so that both username and email are accepted:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.forms import ValidationError

class EmailAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.data['username']
        if '@' in username:
            try:
                username = User.objects.get(email=username).username
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                raise ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['invalid_login'],
                    code='invalid_login',
                    params={'username':self.username_field.verbose_name},
                )
        return username
```

Don't know if there is some setting to set the default Authentication form but you can also override the url in urls.py

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', { 'authentication_form': EmailAuthenticationForm }, name='login'),
```

Raising the ValidationError will prevent 500 errors when an invalid email is submitted. Using the super's definition for "invalid_login" keeps the error message ambiguous (vs a specific "no user by that email found") which would be required to prevent leaking whether an email address is signed up for an account on your service. If that information is not secure in your architecture it might be friendlier to have a more informative error message.

Comment: I am not using auth.views.login. Using custom this is my url url(r'accounts/login', 'login_view',) . If i am giving EmailAuthenticationForm, then the error is login_view() got an unexpected keyword argument 'authentication_form'

Comment: This worked cleanly for me, I actually used my custom user profile (since in my architecture User is not guaranteed to have email address attached). Seems much nicer than customizing the user model or making the username equal to an email (since that allows keeping friend's email private while exposing username for instance).

Answer (score 8):

Django now provides a full example of an extended authentication system with admin and form: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

You can basically copy/paste it and adapt (I didn't need the `date_of_birth` in my case).

It is actually available since Django 1.5 and is still available as of now (django 1.7).

Comment: I follower the [djangoproject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) tutorial and it works perfectly

Answer (score 8):

If you're going to extend user model, you will have to implement custom user model anyway.

Here is an example for Django 1.8. Django 1.7 would require a little bit more work, mostly changing default forms (just take a look  at `UserChangeForm` & `UserCreationForm` in `django.contrib.auth.forms` - that's what you need in 1.7).

user_manager.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
from django.utils import timezone

class SiteUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        today = timezone.now()

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email address must be set')

        email = SiteUserManager.normalize_email(email)
        user  = self.model(email=email,
                          is_staff=False, is_active=True, **extra_fields)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        u = self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
        u.is_staff = True
        u.is_active = True
        u.is_superuser = True
        u.save(using=self._db)
        return u
```

models.py:

```
from mainsite.user_manager import SiteUserManager

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin

class SiteUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email    = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=False)

    is_active   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff    = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = SiteUserManager()

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email
```

forms.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm, UserCreationForm
from mainsite.models import SiteUser

class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = SiteUser
        fields = ("email",)


class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = SiteUser


class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = MyUserChangeForm
    add_form = MyUserCreationForm

    fieldsets = (
        (None,              {'fields': ('email', 'password',)}),
        ('Permissions',     {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',)}),  
        ('Groups',          {'fields': ('groups', 'user_permissions',)}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )

    list_display = ('email', )       
    list_filter = ('is_active', )    
    search_fields = ('email',)       
    ordering = ('email',)


admin.site.register(SiteUser, MyUserAdmin)
```

settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mainsite.SiteUser'
```

Comment: I've test your approach and works, but in my case I had add the `username` field to `SiteUser` model, because, when I execute the `python manage.py makemigrations ...` command I get this output: `ERRORS:
<class 'accounts.admin.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E033) The value of 'ordering[0]' refers to 'username', which is not an attribute of 'accounts.User'.`

Comment: I've add the `username` field to my `User` model with their `null=True` attribute.  In this paste bin entry I did want show the implementation. https://pastebin.com/W1PgLrD9

Answer (score 2):

Other alternatives look too complex for me, so I wrote a snippet that allows to authenticate using username, email, or both, and also enable or disable case sensitive. I uploaded it to pip as [django-dual-authentication](https://github.com/Zeioth/django-dual-authentication).

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.conf import settings

###################################
"""  DEFAULT SETTINGS + ALIAS   """
###################################


try:
    am = settings.AUTHENTICATION_METHOD
except:
    am = 'both'
try:
    cs = settings.AUTHENTICATION_CASE_SENSITIVE
except:
    cs = 'both'

#####################
"""   EXCEPTIONS  """
#####################


VALID_AM = ['username', 'email', 'both']
VALID_CS = ['username', 'email', 'both', 'none']

if (am not in VALID_AM):
    raise Exception("Invalid value for AUTHENTICATION_METHOD in project "
                    "settings. Use 'username','email', or 'both'.")

if (cs not in VALID_CS):
    raise Exception("Invalid value for AUTHENTICATION_CASE_SENSITIVE in project "
                    "settings. Use 'username','email', 'both' or 'none'.")

############################
"""  OVERRIDDEN METHODS  """
############################


class DualAuthentication(ModelBackend):
    """
    This is a ModelBacked that allows authentication
    with either a username or an email address.
    """

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            if ((am == 'email') or (am == 'both')):
                if ((cs == 'email') or cs == 'both'):
                    kwargs = {'email': username}
                else:
                    kwargs = {'email__iexact': username}

                user = UserModel.objects.get(**kwargs)
            else:
                raise
        except:
            if ((am == 'username') or (am == 'both')):
                if ((cs == 'username') or cs == 'both'):
                    kwargs = {'username': username}
                else:
                kwargs = {'username__iexact': username}

                user = UserModel.objects.get(**kwargs)
        finally:
            try:
                if user.check_password(password):
                    return user
            except:
                # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
                # difference between an existing and a non-existing user.
                UserModel().set_password(password)
                return None

    def get_user(self, username):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            return UserModel.objects.get(pk=username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of django-registration allows some nice customisation and might do the job - docs here https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/fad7080fe769/docs/backend-api.rst

Answer (score 1):

```
     if user_form.is_valid():
        # Save the user's form data to a user object without committing.
        user = user_form.save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(user.password)
        #Set username of user as the email
        user.username = user.email
        #commit
        user.save()
```

working perfectly... for django 1.11.4

Answer (score 0):

you can also find an interesting discussion on this topic at the below link :

http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/c943ede66e6807c/2fbf2afeade397eb#2fbf2afeade397eb

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to lookup the username based on the email in the login view. That way you can leave everything else alone:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as auth_login

def _is_valid_email(email):
    from django.core.validators import validate_email
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    try:
        validate_email(email)
        return True
    except ValidationError:
        return False

def login(request):

    next = request.GET.get('next', '/')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username'].lower()  # case insensitivity
        password = request.POST['password']

    if _is_valid_email(username):
        try:
            username = User.objects.filter(email=username).values_list('username', flat=True)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            username = None
    kwargs = {'username': username, 'password': password}
    user = authenticate(**kwargs)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                auth_login(request, user)
                return redirect(next or '/')
            else:
                messages.info(request, "<stvrong>Error</strong> User account has not been activated..")
        else:
            messages.info(request, "<strong>Error</strong> Username or password was incorrect.")

    return render_to_response('accounts/login.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In your template set the next variable accordingly, i.e.

```
<form method="post" class="form-login" action="{% url 'login' %}?next={{ request.GET.next }}" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

And give your username / password inputs the right names, i.e. username, password.

**UPDATE**:

Alternatively, the if _is_valid_email(email): call can be replaced with  if '@' in username. That way you can drop the _is_valid_email function. This really depends on how you define your username. It will not work if you allow the '@' character in your usernames.

Comment: This code is buggy, because username can also have a '@' symbol, so if '@' is present, it is not necessary an email.

Comment: depends on you really, I don't allow username to have @ symbol. If you do you can add another filter query to search through User object by username. PS. username can also be an email, so you have to be careful with how you design your user management.

Comment: Also check out, from django.core.validators import validate_email . You can do a try except ValidationError block with validate_email('your@email.com') .  It might still be buggy depending on your app.

Comment: Of course, you're right, it depends on how the login logic is set up. I mentioned that because the possibility of '@' in username is django's default. Someone can copy your code and have problems when user with username 'Gladi@tor' cannot login because login code thinks it's an email.

Comment: Good call. I hope people understand what it is they are copying. I'll add in the email validation and comment out the current validation, leave it as an alternative. I guess the only other reason why I didn't use the validation apart from my user names not having the @, is that it makes the code less dependent on django.  Things do tend to move around from version to version. Cheers!

Comment: I don't think a filter  call will raise a User.DoesNotExist... This happens with `get`

Answer (score 0):

I think the most quickly way is to create a form inherit from `UserCreateForm`, and then override the `username` field with `forms.EmailField`. Then for every new registration user, they need to signon with their email address.

For example:

**urls.py**

```
...
urlpatterns += url(r'^signon/$', SignonView.as_view(), name="signon")
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms

class UserSignonForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.EmailField()


class SignonView(CreateView):
    template_name = "registration/signon.html"
    model = User
    form_class = UserSignonForm
```

**signon.html**

```
...
<form action="#" method="post">
    ...
    <input type="email" name="username" />
    ...
</form>
...
```

Comment: Downvoted for a couple of reasons. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/778399/538866) is a better way of doing the same thing. And why subclass when you can merely define what widget to use directly in the `UserCreationForm` class? And please do not recommend writing out `<input …` when, surely, `{{form.username}}` is better.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if people are trying to accomplish this, but I found nice (and clean) way to only ask for the email and then set the username as the email in the view before saving.

My UserForm only requires the email and password:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password')
```

Then in my view I add the following logic:

```
if user_form.is_valid():
            # Save the user's form data to a user object without committing.
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)

            user.set_password(user.password)
            #Set username of user as the email
            user.username = user.email
            #commit
            user.save()
```

Comment: Couldn't storing the email in the username cause issues because the username is 30 chars while email is 75 chars?