# Django: how to get a model instance by id

Tags: django, model, instance

I need to pass a model instance to create another model instance with a foreign key. I have the entry id, but if I do,

```
user = User.objects.get(id = request.user.id)
```

But this "user" thing that comes out isn't a model "instance", and when I pass it into another model as a foreign key reference I get an error.

What should I do here? This seems like a intractable problem... If you have a model with a foreign key, to create a new instance of that model you need a fresh instance of the corresponding foreign-key model. But what if that foreign-key model already has a record in the database? If the objects.get() won't give you an "instance", what can you do? You can't exactly create another new instance in the database - which is just wrong, and won't work since the id's are all auto-incremented anyway.

I must be missing something big here....

Comment: What is `user` if it's not a model "instance"? There's no need to fetch the user as you are doing. `request.user` is the model instance of the logged in user.

Comment: 1. Instead of `User.objects.get(id = request.user.id)` you can use `request.user`. 2. "User thing" is a model instance if user is authenticated. Check it with `login_required` decorator for example.

Comment: OK I figured it out.... 

I had a custom User model in my code, and when I defined the other model I accidentally foreign-key linked it to the default User class in Django, no wonder it's complaining. 

To answer Alasdair, the request.user class apparently isn't my custom User class. I used Django's default "auth.authenticate"... maybe I should write my own authenticate or something. Just a big mess. 

The whole reason why I'm going all this way to create a new User class is this weird thing where you can't use email as your user id. The creators of Django are kind of weird on this one.

Comment: @reedvoid http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778382/accepting-email-address-as-username-in-django for example

Comment: Indeed, the correct approach is to create a custom authentication backend, not a custom `User` class -- that's a road to pain no matter how you proceeed.