# Django: Is Base64 of md5 hash of email address under 30 characters?

Tags: python, django

I am investigating since a few hours the best way to use the Email address instead of username in Django authentication. This topic has been discussed many times but the given results are inconsistent.

1) The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778382/accepting-email-address-as-username-in-django) points to a [snippet](http://www.davidcramer.net/code/224/logging-in-with-email-addresses-in-django.html) that distinguishes the username and email simply by having an '@'char in it. The max length of email and username is not equal though and not considered in the answer.

2) The second answer - from the same [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778382/accepting-email-address-as-username-in-django) - from S.Lott (13 votes) is doing some black magic with admin.site.  It doesn't make sense to me what the code is doing, is this the accepted way of doing it short and sweet?

3) Then I found [this solution](http://www.xairon.net/2011/05/django-email-only-authentication/), which seems almost perfect (and makes sense to me):

```
username = uuid.uuid4().hex[:30]
```

It picks only the first 30 chars of a unique Python generated ID as the username.  But there is still a chance of collision. Then I came across a post where someone has claimed

> A base64 encoding of an md5 hash has 25 characters

If thats true, couldn't we take the base64 encoding of an md5 hash of the **email address** and guarantee 100% unique usernames, which are also under 30 character? If this is true, how could this be achieved?

Many Thanks,

Comment: Let's cut this short: Hashes collide, so they are not "100% unique", period.

Comment: MD5 is 128 bits which result in a 22 Base64 characters (128 bits divided by 6 bits/character) or 24 Base64 characters when padded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
>>> from hashlib import md5
>>> h = md5('email@example.com').digest().encode('base64')[:-1]
>>> _
'Vlj/zO5/Dr/aKyJiOLHrbg=='
>>> len(h)
24
```

You can ignore the last char because it's just a new line. The chance of collision is the same as the MD5 hash, you don't lose information when you encode in base64.

```
>>> original = md5('email@example.com').digest()
>>> encoded = original.encode('base64')
>>> original == encoded.decode('base64') 
True
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Since the chance of collision is still given, would this approach be still cleaner than picking the 30 chars from generated ID above?

Comment: Yes. If you just split the UUID, you will be removing information and increasing the chances of collisions.

Comment: That said, the chance for a MD5 collision in your case is small, unless you are Facebook ;)

Comment: hehe nah, I would be happy with 1000 customers. This solution seems perfect for me. Thanks

Comment: It does generate characters that are not allowed in Django usernames

Answer (score 2):

[MD5 hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5_Hash) are always 16 bytes long, and [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encodes groups of 3 bytes to 4 characters; thus (16 / 3 rounded up) => 6 groups of 3, times 4 = 24 characters for a MD5 hash encoded to Base64.

However, note that the above linked Wikipedia page states:

> However, it has since been shown that MD5 is not collision resistant.

So you cannot count on this method giving you unique usernames from email addresses. Producing them is very easy with the help of the [`hashlib` module](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html):

```
>>> from hashlib import md5
>>> md5('foo@bar.com').digest().encode('base64').strip()
'862kBc6JC2+CBAlN6xLYqA=='
```

Comment: Thank you. Does the .strip() in this case just removes the the new line?

Answer (score 2):

`UUID` is 128bit, thus you could apply base64 on it directly to get a 22-chars long string (by removing fixed padding `'=='`, as Gumbo suggests in comments of the question)

```
>>> import base64
>>> len(base64.urlsafe_b64encode(uuid.uuid4().bytes).rstrip('='))
22
```

Here, the `urlsafe_b64encode` and the stripping of `'='` are used to avoid chars that `User.username` field does not like, including `'/' '+'` and `'='`

Also, UUID has two bits of fixed `'10'`(hence the 17th char in the hex representation is always `8,9,A,B`) and four bits of versions, check [the wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29).
Thus you could throw away the 4+2=6bits along w/ 2 effective bits to get a 30-chars long hex string:

```
>>> s = uuid.uuid4().hex
>>> len(s[:12] + s[13:16] + s[17:])
30
```

In this way you only throw away 2 effective bits instead of 8 when simply slicing s by `s[:30]`, and you could expect better *uniqueness* (1/4 coding space of uuid at most).

Comment: Thank you for the new solution. Effectively if I used unique email addresses though instead of uuid (see accepted answer) I wouldn't have to throw away any bits since its under 30 and hence the most unique way of doing it, right?

Comment: @Kave yes, its always better to use meaningful unique keys. You could still use `urlsafe_b64encode` and stripping off `=`.