# How to make customer's email as the username in UserCreationForm / User Model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-users

I'm using the UserModel and the UserCreationForm in Django. However, instead of requiring a username, I want to use the customer's email as the login information (i.e. completely bypass / ignore the username field).

1. How do I go about making the username field to be optional in the User Model
2. How do I turn email into the customer's "username"? In turn, how do I make this email field to be required then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accepting email address as username in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778382/accepting-email-address-as-username-in-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Just make the username field optional in your form and to the model pass the email as the username, after stripping out '@' from the email.

2) Create a custom authentication backend (this will accept either the username or email):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class EmailOrUsernameModelBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        if '@' in username:
            kwargs = {'email': username}
        else:
            kwargs = {'username': username}
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(**kwargs)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

chage your settings accordingly :

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'myoursite.backends.EmailOrUsernameBackend', # Custom Authentication to accept usernamee or email
)
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! I just got another idea from your post though. Instead of entering the username, how do I get it so that everything in the email before the @ sign (ex: goelv from goelv@gmail.com) becomes the username? Is that something I would handle in the view? I'm new at this, thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, that's not very realistic.... what if two users have email addresses masteryoda@gmail.com and masteryoda@yahoo.com, they can't have the same username

Comment: i'm working on a system where the first part would be unique so it could be viable

Comment: If you really want to do it, you can just not display the username field in your template and edit your view to pass the username to the form like this: http://snippi.com/s/f1vipav