# Can't display email field using django allauth

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-allauth

I have problem that in my login.html file the email field won't be displayed. Here is the html code:

```
<form method="POST" id="signup_form" action="{% url 'account_login' %}" class="registration-form">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-email form-control" id="form-email"> -->
        {{ form.email }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Lozinka" class="form-about-yourself form-control" id="form-about-yourself"></input> -->
        {{ form.password}}
    </div>

    {% if redirect_field_value %}
        <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
    {% endif %}

    <a class="button secondaryAction" href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">
        {% trans "Zaboravili ste oznaku?" %}
    </a>
    <br>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Prijavite se</button>
</form>
```

So the email field wont be displayed, but the passwod field is. Also the password field is displayed but I cannot customize it. Here is how I'm trying to do that:

```
class AuthenticationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Login form
    """
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['email', 'password']


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AuthenticationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['email'].widget = forms.EmailInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Email adresa*',
            'required': True,
            'class': "form-email form-control"
            })

        self.fields['password'].widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Lozinka*',
            'required': True,
            'class': "form-first-name form-control"
            })
```

I am having all of this for my signup page and it works fine. I tried with *form.as_p* and it works fine, but I want my own style. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Use `{{ form.login }}` to display the email field, instead of `{{ form.email }}`

---

From https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/forms.py you can see that Django login form has three fields, login, password and remember. So in you case just do

```
<form method="POST" id="signup_form" action="{% url 'account_login' %}" class="registration-form">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-email form-control" id="form-email"> -->
        {{ form.login}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Lozinka" class="form-about-yourself form-control" id="form-about-yourself"></input> -->
        {{ form.password}}
    </div>

    {% if redirect_field_value %}
        <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
    {% endif %}

    <a class="button secondaryAction" href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">
        {% trans "Zaboravili ste oznaku?" %}
    </a>
    <br>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Prijavite se</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a django expert, but if you only want to style your inputs, it might be better to use [django-widget-tweaks](https://github.com/kmike/django-widget-tweaks). It keeps styling and python code seperated.

So first you can install it with:

```
pip install django-widget-tweaks
```

Then add 'widget_tweaks' to INSTALLED_APPS.

Load widget_tweaks in your template:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
```

And in your case you would put something like:

```
{% render_field form.email placeholder='Email adresa*' required="required" class="form-email form-control" %}

{% render_field form.password placeholder='Lozinka*' required="required" class="form-first-name form-control" type="password" %}
```

in your template instead of:

```
{{ form.email }}
{{ form.password }}
```

If you choose to do this, I think you don't need `__init__()` method in your `AuthenticationForm`

EDIT1:
In my case I also had to add `type="password"` to the password `render_field` tag

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the email field is still not displayed. The password field is, and it is changed, but there is no email field in html when I run the server.

Comment: If you are using Django's default login view for authentication, then Django passes `AuthenticationForm` from `django.contrib.auth.forms` to your template. This form only contains username and password fields and that is the reason your email field is not displayed. If you want to have email field used to login users, then read [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778382/accepting-email-address-as-username-in-django) answers and see what works for you. The simplest solution of course is to use username field for user logins.

Comment: In my case, even using `django-widget-tweaks`, the email field was displayed using `form.login`. For example, `{% render_field form.login class+="uk-input" %}`.