# Creating Django users with just an email and password - UserCreationForm

Tags: python, django, django-users

I have the need of create an user account in my application using just the `email` and `password` fields. Due to this, my custom user model in my models.py is:

I customize the UserManager to create user

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
            email = self.normalize_email(email)
            user = self.model(email = email, **extra_fields)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

And my User model is:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True,
            help_text=_('Required. Letters, digits and ''@/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[RegexValidator(r'^[\w.@+-]+$', _('Enter a valid email address.'), 'invalid')
        ])

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this site.'),
    )

    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Usuarios en la plataforma'

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.email)
```

In my settings I've add:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = ‘my_app_name.User’
```

---

**CREATE USERS** - `UserCreationForm` pre-built class

To create an user, I am using of the `UserCreationForm` class [pre-built in the django core.](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L64)

In this class the username field is used [such as denoted here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L87)

According to the above, in my forms.py I have:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm, UserCreationForm

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = get_user_model()

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = get_user_model()

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        fields = ("email", "password1", "password2",)
        model = get_user_model()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["email"].label = "Email address"
```

When I try execute the python manage.py makemigrations  , I get this  traceback output error

```
    bgarcial@elpug ‹ testing ●● › : ~/workspace/ihost_project
[1] % python manage.py makemigrations accounts 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/ihost/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/ihost/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/ihost/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/ihost/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/ihost/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 23, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/ihost/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/ihost/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/ihost/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/bgarcial/workspace/ihost_project/accounts/admin.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .forms import CustomUserChangeForm, CustomUserCreationForm
  File "/home/bgarcial/workspace/ihost_project/accounts/forms.py", line 16, in <module>
    class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/ihost/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 257, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (username) specified for User
(ihost) 
bgarcial@elpug ‹ testing ●● › : ~/workspace/ihost_project
```

Of course, I am using `UserCreationForm` django class core, I am forcing to use the django core functionalities in which the username field is required

How to can I remove the username or modify this?

I know the modify the django core is not recommended, but, how to can I create an user without include the username field making use of `UserCreationForm` django class core?

I try override the save method of my form in where I create the users, but I don't have clear the process, I think that the core of my inconvenient is in the use of `UserCreationForm` django class core   ..

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("email", "password1", "password2",)
        model = get_user_model()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["email"].label = "Email address"

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]

        # Tell to Django that not check the username

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

If somebody can point me in the right direction will be very much appreciated. :)

Comment: @Alasdair I've type the entire traceback. Thanks to you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution that works.

anyways, feel free to suggest better solutions!

Like my inconvenient/error was related with the use of the `UserCreationForm` class [pre-built in the django core](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L64) which [use the username field in their logic](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L87), then I proceeded to make the following:

In my forms.py in my class `CustomUserCreationForm` is a child of the class `UserCreationForm`, I've override/add to `Meta` class the attribute `fields`,  using the `email` field instead of `username` field.
[This question post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29638766/2773461) help me with it.

My class `CustomUserCreationForm` stay as follow:

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email',)
```

Then, I proceeded to perform my migrations:

```
[1] % python manage.py makemigrations accounts 
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'accounts.admin.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E033) The value of 'ordering[0]' refers to 'username', which is not an attribute of 'accounts.User'.
```

This error showed me that the `username` field is not an attribute of my `User` model.
This means that Django follows trying to ask the username field, even though I overwritten the `fields` value with the `email` field.

Of course this is logic because I am still inherit from `UserCreationForm` class [pre-built in the django core](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L64)

Then, I've add the `username` field to my User model with null=True attribute, and of this way, the username does not required in the user account creation:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    # I had add the username field despite that I don't use in my User model
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, null=True,
            help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and ''@/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[RegexValidator(r'^[\w.@+-]+$', _('Enter a valid username.'), 'invalid')
        ])

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True,
            help_text=_('Required. Letters, digits and ''@/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[RegexValidator(r'^[\w.@+-]+$', _('Enter a valid email address.'), 'invalid')
        ])

  ...
```

Of this way, I execute my migrations

```
bgarcial@elpug ‹ testing ●● › : ~/workspace/ihost_project
[1] % python manage.py makemigrations accounts 
Migrations for 'accounts':
  accounts/migrations/0001_initial.py:
    - Create model User
(ihost) 
bgarcial@elpug ‹ testing ●● › : ~/workspace/ihost_project

python manage.py migrate accounts ...
```

And my username field still persist in my custom user schema, just that is not required and when I created an user from my `UserCreateForm` class which inherit from `UserCreationForm`, I can create an user account with just email and password

[image]

I don`t know if this is the best approach to address this inconvenient.
Feel free to suggest improvements!