# Allowing both email and username login in Django project

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a Django project for a school, and there are three main kinds of users - parents, teachers, and students. For parents and teachers, I would like them to log in using email (they are currently using email logins for a legacy system).

However, for students, I would like them to log in using the conventional username approach (since young kids don't have emails). Is this possible to do in Django or is there only one User Authentication model allowed?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332190/django-login-with-email#37332393 except you have to check for both email and username. I suggest you verify both and throw an error if two users are returned (imagine a user with an email **as** username)

Comment: Thank you. So it's possible for a field to accept either username and email then. So parents/teachers would use email, and kids to use their usernames?

Answer (score 8):

You can create separate `AuthenticationEmailBackend` just for logging by email and add it to `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` in settings. In this way different `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` are used as alternatives if authentication fails for previous `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`.

**app/auth.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class AuthenticationEmailBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if getattr(user, 'is_active', False) and user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    ...
    "app.auth.AuthenticationEmailBackend",
)
```

If you leave default `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` in a list users can login by either username or email.

Answer (score 5):

Seems **request** parameter is needed in authenticate method from Django 1.11:

```
def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None)
```

According to what is said in [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/).

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you earn enough reputation, you will gain privileges to upvote answers you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 2):

A simple backend which allows you to login with either an email address or a username.

It should be combined with another backend for checking permissions:

**settings.py:**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'myproject.accounts.backends.EmailOrUsernameModelBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend' )
```

**account/backends.py:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class EmailOrUsernameModelBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        if '@' in username:
            kwargs = {'email': username}
        else:
            kwargs = {'username': username}
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(**kwargs)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

**and for case-insensitive :**

```
class EmailOrUsernameModelBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        # user_model = get_user_model()
        if '@' in username:
            # kwargs = {'email': username}
            field = 'email'
        else:
            # kwargs = {'username': username}
            field = 'username'
        try:

            case_insensitive_username_field = '{}__iexact'.format(field)
            user = User._default_manager.get(**{case_insensitive_username_field: username})

            # user = User.objects.get(**kwargs)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Answer (score 2):

For Django 3.0:

```
# myapp/backends.py

from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend

from .models import MyUser


class EmailAuthenticationBackend(BaseBackend):

def authenticate(self, request, **kwargs):
    email = kwargs['username'].lower()  # If you made email case insensitive add lower()
    password = kwargs['password']
    try:
        my_user = MyUser.objects.get(email=email)
    except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
        return None
    else:
        if my_user.is_active and my_user.check_password(password):
            return my_user
    return None

def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        return MyUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

This works for Django 2.0 and probably previous versions:

```
# myapp/backends.py

from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

from .models import MyUser


class EmailAuthenticationBackend(ModelBackend):

    def authenticate(self, request, **kwargs):
        email = kwargs['username']
        password = kwargs['password']
        try:
            my_user = MyUser.objects.get(email=email)
        except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if my_user.is_active and my_user.check_password(password):
                return my_user
        return None
```

(Not sure if it is a good idea to extend the ModelBackend, you can crete your own class)

And then, for both versions:

```
# settings.py

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "myapp.backends.EmailAuthenticationBackend",
]
```

Answer (score 0):

in models.py

```
class UserDet(models.Model):
       email = models.EmailField(max_length=20)
 
       userName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

in views.py

```
def user_login(request):
    response_data={}
    if request.session.has_key('login_id'):  #If user already logedin send to dashboard else check userid and password
        return render(request, '/dashboard.html')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':  # If request method is post then only process request
            #print('here in login')
            try:

                username = request.POST.get('username')
                password = request.POST.get('pass')

                if '@' in username: #check for email
                    try:
                         
                        for u in UserDet.objects.filter(email=username):
                            #username=u['userName']
                            
                            username=u.userName
                    except:
                        response_data['code']=1000
                        response_data['status']='fail'
                        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")

                if not request.POST.get('rememberme', None):  # check user select the remember me or not if yes then create session that expire after long time
                    #print('seeing it 0')
                    request.session.set_expiry(0)
                 
                
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password) # Check user exist or not
                
                if user:  #if user exist then
                    if user.is_active: #check user is active or not if active then successfully loged in else send error
                        login(request,user)
                        
                        update_last_login(None, user)
                        request.session['login_id'] = user.id
                        response_data['code']=800
                        response_data['status']='success'
                        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
                        #return render(request, '/dashboard.html')
                    else:
                        response_data['code']=900  #Error for User is not active
                        response_data['status']='fail'
                        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
                        #return HttpResponse("Your account was inactive.")
                else: #Error or Invalid username or password
                    #print("Someone tried to login and failed.")
                    #print("They used username: {} and password: {}".format(username,password))
                    response_data['code']=1000
                    response_data['status']='fail'
                    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
            
            except:
                response_data['code']=1001
                response_data['status']='fail'
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
        else: #Return to index
                return redirect('/', {})
```